# Nautilus and Disks doesn't show mobile device but shows portable devices like pendrives

Tags: usb, nautilus, usb-drive

My Ubuntu 17.04 doesn't show my mobile phone memory on Nautilus as well as on Disks. However when I use gMTP it works perfectly fine. I checked with ADB and it also detects my device when I connect with USB debugging on. The problem is that i worked fine earlier but it just stopped working automatically. Strange thing is that its not power or port issue because my pendrives works fine and my phone begins to charge also. Just the nautilus cant read it. Can anyone suggest me a solution. Please!!!

Comment: On my phone, after I connect it I need to unlock the screen, check the USB connection notification and choose to allow and MTP connection (AKA "Transferring Media Files").  Otherwise, it just charges from the USB port.

Comment: I do it every time. gMTP doesnt work if MTP isnt chosen first on the device.

Comment: Do you have `jmtpfs` installed?

Comment: installed jmtpfs... connected device,selected mtp, run jmtpfs,android device detected but error: `fuse: missing moutnpoint parameter`